# Whta if I don't use app/webroot/index.php

Tags: cakephp-2.0

I know that the index.php requires many files like core,dispatch,bootstrap and so on.This time in my project,I directly use a html inseide which has a ,and 
the href is "topath/app/houses/init"(created by myself).The question is that,how about the index.php and the files it requires?Should they be required actually?
 Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

yes index.php required those files to load cake api, and dispatcher api's.

if you need a plain html then you can use following structure

- topath/app/index.html which contain anchor tag to redirect on your
  specified app
- topath/app/houses is an cakephp app that contains all your houses app
  content

if you have multiple cakephp app then you can seperate cake api

keep cake api out side from app

- mainapp/cake/ include all cakephp api lib
- mainapp/houses/ include all houses app code
- update mainapp/houses/app/webroot/index.php to load cake api from
  mainapp/cake/

and so on......

hope it will help you